# generate XML file using form data

Tags: xml, forms

I'm looking for easy and flexible way to generate XML file from HTML form data - one solution for any form. It would be nice to convert XML to some form also, so communication in both ways. Does such an XML - HTML form integration tool exist?

I've heard about Xforms, but apparently browsers don't support it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure browsers ever supported xform, but it's not dead either. You can always try XSLTForm at http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms.

For some generic code to get xml from an html form, you could start with a function like this one and adjust it to your taste.

```
function getFormXml(){
var sXml;
var sType;
var sValue;
sXml = "<xml>" + "\n"
$( "form input" ).each(function() {
    sType = $(this).attr("type");
    sValue = $(this).val();
    if(sType == "checkbox" || sType == "radio") {
        sXml = sXml + "<input type='" + $(this).attr("type") + "' checked='" + $(this).prop("checked") + "'>" + sValue + "</input>" + "\n";
    } else {
        sValue = $(this).val();
        sXml = sXml + "<input type='" + $(this).attr("type") + "'>" + sValue + "</input>" + "\n";
    }   
});
sXml = sXml + "</xml>" + "\n";
alert(sXml);
}
```

Try the jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/raybiss/vRLPw/

Getting XML to HTML is another story...

Comment: XSLTForm is something I was looking for!